# GCE : Do I need a secondary disk for standard persistent disk?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I am using persistent disks to store database files.
Google says its Standard persistent disks (HDD) is redundant and reliable
Will the disk crash or go into read-only mode?

**Do I need a secondary disk for backup?**

Comment: Do you trust Google? Do you trust their standard persistent disks? Do you trust that you'll never need to restore data due to corruption, deletion or other inadvertent or unknown factors or reasons? Etc., etc. Your justification for backing up your data isn't simply a matter of whether or not the underlying disk is reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using [snapshots](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/snapshots) for backups?

Comment: snapshots does not help in my case.  I am running mysql in Google Container which mounts the persistent disk to store the sql data.  Do I need setup a slave node (mysql slave) to backup the data in real-time?

Comment: As queowerty said above - it depends. How critical is your data? Can you take dumps of your mysql database periodically and shove it into GCS? How often would you need to do backups to not lose "too much data" should the PD become unreadable? You can also review the PD SLA (https://cloud.google.com/compute/sla) to see if it is sufficient for your use case.